# Creating a stamp with pypdf does not work for simple PDF file, works for others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am following the `pypdf` documentation here:
https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html#watermark-overlay

I want to overlay one PDF over another (or overlay text over a PDF). The below code works for certain more complex `overlay.pdf`, but doesn't work for the simple `overlay.pdf` linked below. I see the base PDF, but not the overlay. What could the issue be?

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/ygqttuti4ed7cc2dz1c4u/h?rlkey=khdu0k5stkt205p4mcgca5n0i&dl=0

```
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

stamp = PdfReader("overlay.pdf").pages[0]
writer = PdfWriter(clone_from="form_1099_nec_page_4.pdf")
for page in writer.pages:
    page.merge_page(stamp, over=True)

writer.write("merged.pdf")
```

This `overlay.pdf` was generated with the following code, in case that's relevant.

```
wkhtmltopdf_path = getattr(settings, 'WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH', None)
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkhtmltopdf_path)
with open('overlay.html', 'r') as html_file:
    html_content = html_file.read()

pdf_data = pdfkit.from_string(html_content, False, configuration=config)

with open('overlay.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_file.write(pdf_data)
```

Comment: I downloaded the pdfs and I was able to apply the watermark, with `pypdf.__version__` 3.16.4

Comment: Hm... strangest thing. I tried with your version and it still doesn't work, but works with another `overlay.pdf` as earlier. Thanks a lot for the feedback, I will try this in a different environment (linux, I am on mac) and see if the problem remains.

Comment: tested on linux

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Maybe it has something to do with the PDF viewers we use, no idea.

Comment: Have you tried with `over=True` as proposed by @KJ in his answer?

Comment: Yes, ran with `over=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are some underlying issues to consider when using stamps especially with forms.

The source form in this case will not have been a true PDF but a transparent textual XFA in a PDF wrapper. See it here.
[image]

The blue fields are the areas for text Overlay from the keyboard or FDF file.

When normally using such Restricted "Exclusively Adobe PRO" files the reader version is allowed limited access to those fields to allow the visible over stamping.

In this case a neutered opaque pictorial reproduction of the page has been used so we cannot see the background. thus the only option is OVERLAY (stamp) the text onto the image. You cannot apply an underlay. the correct syntax will thus be

```
page.merge_page(stamp, over=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this work for you with the example `overlay.pdf` provided?

Comment: You are correct. This is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by first converting the base PDF (`form_1099_nec_page_4.pdf`) to JPG, then converting it back to PDF.

The issue is potentially with XFA as mentioned by @K J and the above process could be removing the XFA layer.

EDIT: Reversing which PDF is base and which is overlay also fixes the issue and it is a superior solution. Image conversion degrades data quality.

Comment: You are correct, reversing the files fixes the issue and there is no degradation in data that way.